# when to choose typeahead and dropdown component

Tags: angularjs, html, design-patterns, drop-down-menu, user-experience

I am about to design a webpage wherein I got confused between few components which suits.

Here, I would like to understand what is the best scenario for choosing between typeahead and dropdown menu as both provide a list of values.

Reference: https://pineconellc.github.io/angular-foundation/

Thanks in advance.

P.S. This is just a subjective question.

Comment: This is more of a UX question rather than a programmatic one. Consider using http://ux.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: okay. I'll do there. Thanks @Tr1stan

Comment: I posted the same on ux website and got answer http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/94681/when-to-choose-one-between-dropdown-and-typeahead